# Certifications for Card.io security for not transmitting card data

Tags: card.io

Is there any certifications like

> PCI/DSS etc.

that card.io have, to certify that card information is not transmitted ?

I just want to have this information as card information security is paramount for the kind of application I am working on and implementation will depend on these parameters.

Thanks

Comment: I see no documents on the official website so you may have to trust their _card.io does not store or transmit credit card numbers_ statement

Answer (score 0):

There are no official certifications and I believe even if there was one, you would need to get your app certified (the library would not be enough).

The source code is publicly available and you can rebuild it from source if you need to. See [Android repository](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source), [iOS repository](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source), and a [common code dmz one](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-dmz).